# How to measure GPu temperature MBP 13 mid-2010?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature, gpu

My question is very simple. I have some troubles with my MBP 13' mid-2010 (kernels panics, crashs and reboots). I think the problem is coming from the GPU (Nividia 320m). One solution could be to change the thermal paste on the GPU but before doing this I want to know the temperature of the GPU.

I use iStat Pro but it doesn't propose to measure this temperature. Do you know if it's possible? And if yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have an MBP 15" mid-2010 and I was able to measure a lot of temperatures (including, I'm fairly sure, the GPU temperature) using [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/). They have a 14-day trial version so it costs nothing to try.

Edit: here's a crop from a screenshot on my older MBP 15" mid-2010 showing the latest version of iStat Menus. Notice the plethora of GPU sensors.

[image: iStat Menus screenshot]

Comment: And which is the name of the sensor? I don't have any GPU sensor in my iStat Menus.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide a screenshot.

Comment: I confirm that I don't have this sensors in my case. I think this is due to the fact that MBP 15 (mid-2010) has two GPU (Intel + Nvidia). Thus the design of the MBP 15 is not the same as MBP 13 (only one Nvidia GPU).